# What executable/applet is run when choosing 'Customize' in notification area?

Tags: windows-7, group-policy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 7 notification area settings are locked](https://superuser.com/questions/216579/windows-7-notification-area-settings-are-locked)

Apologies for the seemingly obvious question but my googlefu is failing me.

In order to allow users to customise the notification area (because why wouldn't we?), we need to add the allowed executable, applet, mmc, whatever it is to be allowed on our Group Policy. Unfortunately I can't find quite **what** needs to be added.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

(Not conclusive maybe, but could point you in the right direction.)

You can find it in the registry at `HKCU\Software\Classes\LocalSettings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\TrayNotify`

[CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner) refers to it as *Tray Notification Cache*.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, the executables involved are `%windir%\system32\dllhost.exe` and `explorer.exe`.

Possibly related: that control panel applet can be started from the command line with
`control.exe /name Microsoft.NotificationAreaIcons`.