# Cannot enable Notification Area in Windows 7

Tags: windows, taskbar, group-policy, notifications, notification-area

In 64-bit Windows 7, I cannot enable the notification area in the taskbar at all.  Every time I try to customize the notification and system icon settings, it says "Some settings are managed by your system administrator." and only allows me to show/hide the clock.  I even tried going to Group Policy (gpedit.msc) in `User Configuration` -> `Start Menu and Taskbar` and disabling `Hide the notification area`, but it has no effect; the system behaves as if this prevention is enabled.  There is no administrative or domain setting that would be causing this, and if I go to "Resultant Set of Policy" (rsop.msc) it even shows the setting I made that `Hide the notification area` is disabled.  Other 64-bit Windows 7 systems that were installed from a different OS build, on the same network, have no such problem.

Why would Windows 7 prevent me from showing the notification area?  How can I enable it?

Comment: Just to clarify: Are you actually on a domain or not?  Does it behave the same way if you log in as a different user?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows 7 notification area settings are locked](http://superuser.com/questions/216579/windows-7-notification-area-settings-are-locked)

Comment: I would also point out that if you are in a domain and you are not a domain admin you would not see machine policies in RSOP.

Comment: The computer is on a domain, *but* had this problem right off the bat from when I installed the OS, even before it ever joined the domain.  The OS was installed from a deployed build, but I don't understand why this would prevent showing the notification area.  Something other than the domain settings must be the root cause.  I'm not convinced that my issue is a duplicate of the one referenced, but it doesn't look like that one was solved either.  What on earth could be causing Windows to prohibit showing the notification area if Group Policy is set to allow it??  What else can be done?

Comment: C'mon, doesn't anyone have any more answers about this issue?